# Can VisualSVN and Team Foundation Server client co-exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, visualsvn

I currently run Visual Studio 2008 SP1 connecting to Team Foundation Server. I want to try out the VisualSVN client connecting to a separate repository I have in SVN. Is it possible to install the VisualSVN client on my existing dev machine such that I can use VisualSVN for some of my solutions and TFS for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used both VisualSVN and TFS together on the same machine with both VS 2005 and 2008 with no problems, with the same goal you have. It worked fine.

Comment: Yes, VisualSVN activates only if solution files stored in Subversion working copy.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak for this particular configuration, but I used our main source code provider ([SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/)) at the same time with VisualSVN inside Visual Studio 2008 (without and later with SP1) and had no issues at all. VisualSVN seems to be very well behaved and well written, stable, mature.

Marc